# Laravel : no errors and no update on database happens after saving the edit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have two tables, `user` and `technicien`, with a one to one relation. After editing technicien information through edit form and saving, no update happens on database and no errors as well.

Here is my code:

**controllers**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $user = $technicien->user;
    return view('technicien.edit',['technicien'=>$technicien])->with('user',$user);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // do some request validation

    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $technicien->update($request->all());
    $technicien->user->update($request->get('user'));
    $user->nom = $request->update('nom');

    return redirect('/technicien');
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Technicien</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $technicien->technicien  ) }}" method="update">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}


             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nom">Nom</label>
            <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[nom]" value="{{$user->nom}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[prenom]" value="{{$user->prenom}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Email</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[email]" value="{{$user->email}}" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">moyenne Avis</label>
            <input type="text"  name="moyenne_avis" class="form-control" value ="{{$technicien->moyenne_avis}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Etat Technicien</label>
            <input type="text"  name="actif" class="form-control" value ="{{$technicien->actif}}" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
        </div>
            </div>




        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/technicien/{id}/edit', 'TechnicienController@edit');
Route::patch('/technicien/{id}', 'TechnicienController@update')-
>name('technicien.update');
```

Comment: You want to update user and user's`nom` field of a  $technicien ?

Comment: nom, premon and email from table user, moyenne and actif from table technicien (technicien inherits from user)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass parameters to update function.

Read [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   $technicien=technicien::find($id);
   $technicien->update($request->all());
   $technicien->user->update([
     'nom' => $request->nom,
     'premon' => $request->premon,
     'email' => $request->email
   ]);

   return redirect('/technicien');
}
```

Also from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models)

> You should define which model attributes you want
>   to make mass assignable. You may do this using the $fillable property
>   on the model.

Comment: Thank you but nothing changed

Comment: @IT2704 Are those fields in `$fillable` array of model ?

Comment: Could you help me to do it please ?

Comment: add this to user model `protected $fillable = ['nom','premon','email'];`

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin could you help with this please ?